# Prevent everyone except customer to read DB data

Tags: encryption, database

We are planning an application that must store sensitive data.
Data is coming from other sources, the application will be a "collector" of third party data.

We need to encrypt database data so no one (also DB admin) can read DB data except the customer.
If data were inserted directly by the customer, we could have encrypted data using a key generated by the customer, but data is coming from other sources, there is a background thread that fills data in the DB, customer can only see and search data.

So the problem is how can we encrypt data without having decryption key (asymmetric encryption?) and giving the customer the ability to read that data?

If using asymmetric encryption, we must give the customer the private key, but doing this the customer will not be able to use our web application from any device, as it would need to install private key on every device used to access the web application (is it correct?)

The schema of the application is this:

1. Background application that writes data to the database, collecting from other sources

2. Web application used by the customer to view and search data in database (no editing)

3. Database with encrypted data that only customer can see

Comment: If done properly (depending on the details), asymmetric encryption should be enough - with the customer having the private key and getting ciphertexts. Of course this may be too slow / bandwidth intense depending on the DB operations you need.

Comment: Yes: asymmetric encryption, but... Among issues: metadata likely won't be encrypted (like when an encrypted data blob got written). For many encryption schemes, length of data is not hidden (which can be revealing, e.g. for the "medical antecedents" fields, 4 chars is likely to be `none`, knowing that is of value to an insurance company). There's also the issue of data integrity. And of course encrypted data (using standard asymmetric or symmetric crypto) can't be processed: sorted, queried for some criteria... There's no silver bullet in DB encryption.

Comment: The question is not clear. `we could have encrypted data using a key generated by the customer` so the application server admin agrees with the DB admin, and all data of the users gone. You should make a clear distinction of your system like have many application servers, how many DB server, and who trust who. Also, what kind of operations a user can do with the encrypted data.